Unable to Scrape Google Maps with Cheerio
I'd just like to begin with this is my first time using the Cheerio Library so I could be making a simple mistake. I am attempting to scrape a Google Maps page for the phone number listed. When I use a JQuery via dev console on the site I am able to return the text, but when I use the same div class within Google Apps Scripts my results are always empty.
The code I am using is very simple. This code returns the following error :"We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.". However, if I were to do this within the dev console I would not receive an error using jquery.
The website I am attempting to scrape is here.
function getContent_(url) {
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
}
function testScrape(){
  const content = getContent_('https://www.google.com/maps/place/AutoZone+Auto+Parts/@33.6938582,-78.88908,15z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x890069a9c33250a3:0x8ce735a50e16e70b!8m2!3d33.6938582!4d-78.88908!16s%2Fg%2F1tdl2f1b?entry=ttu');
const $ = Cheerio.load(content);

Logger.log($('div.rogA2c'));
}


Consider using a headless browser like Puppeteer or Selenium. These tools can execute JavaScript and interact with dynamic content, allowing you the scrape data that isn't immediately available in the static HTML. If you still want to try using UrlFetchApp, you might need to set appropriate headers and a user-agent string to mimic a real browser.
Also I recommend checking div class is correct or not. Because sometime companies making scraper preventer with changing the class name continiously or once.
function getContent_(url) {
    const options = {
        'method': 'get',
        'headers': {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'
        }
    };
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
}

function testScrape(){
    const content = getContent_('https://www.google.com/maps/place/AutoZone+Auto+Parts/@33.6938582,-78.88908,15z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x890069a9c33250a3:0x8ce735a50e16e70b!8m2!3d33.6938582!4d-78.88908!16s%2Fg%2F1tdl2f1b?entry=ttu');
    const $ = Cheerio.load(content);

    Logger.log($('div.rogA2c').text());
}

Another solving approach:
You can use vision tools which are available everywhere in GitHub, also you can find tutorials too. It's nearly impossible to outdate. It has long lifespan :)
Recommended Solution I have tried
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/maps/place/AutoZone+Auto+Parts/@33.6938582,-78.88908,15z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x890069a9c33250a3:0x8ce735a50e16e70b!8m2!3d33.6938582!4d-78.88908!16s%2Fg%2F1tdl2f1b?entry=ttu');

    await page.waitForSelector('div.rogA2c');

    const text = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector('div.rogA2c')?.textContent || 'Not Found';
    });

    console.log(text);

    await browser.close();
})();

Result
915 US-501, Myrtle Beach, SC 29577, United States


Thank you for attempting this, I copied your code and still ran into the same results.  My goal was to keep everything within GAS, but it seems like there are limitations to what I can do and may need to use another system alongside GAS.

You can use puppeteer or another automation tools. Every automation tool should fit you I think, if you able to look website and get the idea.

I added working code now, I tested it for you. It is about dynamic waiting I think because website the div you are expecting coming very lately. Thats why you couldn't :)

The data is available in the static HTML in a JSON payload, then injected into the page later.

I was able to build off of your puppeteer solution to get the results I wanted. Thank you! Unfortunately, I was not able to use your GAS solution, so I will have to try to combine node js/puppeteer with GAS.

The data is added dynamically to the document, but is also available in the static HTML (viewable by writing the retrieved content to disk with DriveApp.createFile("test.html", response.getContentText()); or looking at view-source: in the browser):
function myFunction() { // default GAS function name
  const url = "<Your URL>";
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const phone = response.getContentText().match(/\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}/)[0];
  console.log(phone); // => (843) 626-1964
}

You could parse the JSON from the script and traverse it if you want this to be more robust to phone number format changes, but this should be reasonably safe and is certainly the easiest approach from a coding perspective. JSON structures and CSS class names can change just as easily as the phone format.
